# sql sorting inside group by with two column

Tags: mysql, sql

My table:

```
id  | request |  subject     | date
1   |    5    |      1       |  576677
2   |    2    |      3       |  576698 
3   |    5    |      1       |  576999 
4   |    2    |      3       |  586999
```

Need to select unique records by two columns(request,subject) with showing last inserted id's.

My query:

```
SELECT *,MAX(id) 
FROM `tbl` 
GROUP BY CONCAT(`request_id`, `subject_id`) 
HAVING (COUNT(`request_id`)>1 order by MAX(id) desc
```

But results:

```
id  | request |  subject     | date
2   |    2    |      3       |  576698 
1   |    5    |      1       |  576677
```

How to get records with id's 3 and 4 ?

Comment: what should be the output if there is one row : `5 | 5 | 2 | 586754`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT MIN(id) id, request, subject, MAX(`date`) `date`
FROM `tbl`
GROUP BY request, subject;
```

See it run on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cfd89f/1).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
SELECT T.* 
FROM T
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT MAX(`ID`) as ID,`request`,`subject` 
    FROM T 
    GROUP BY `request`,`subject`
    HAVING COUNT(`ID`) > 1
)AS T1 ON T.ID = T1.ID
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cf69f/4)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all. My result is

```
SELECT MAX(id), id, request, subject, date
FROM `tbl`
GROUP BY request, subject having count(request)>1 order by MAX(id) desc
```